# Railroad Tycoon II screen resolution

Tags: railroad-tycoon-2

I have Railroad Tycoon II, bought in Steam.

I want to know if there is any way to prevent the black bands on left/right of the game screen. I went to options and set it to the highest resolution and screen size.

I know that the game is old, and that's the reason for these black bands... but if there is some "hack" to make it go full screen...

Comment: did you try to find an *.ini or *.txt file? Lot of classic games just take there resolutions out of an textfile which you could then manually modify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an old game, so the resolution and aspect ratio's are a bit dated. The trick is to not pick the highest resolution, but one that has the same aspect ratio as your screen. For example, 800 x 600 has an aspect ratio of 4:3. You probably want something 1280 x 720 for a Full HD (1920 x 1080) screen, because that has the same aspect ratio of 16:9.

Comment: You meant 720p = 1280 x 720. Wanted to edit but would have to add useless characters because edit needs at least 6 chars. Hopefully you can edit it as author.

Comment: @StampedeXV Yes, you are completely right. Thanks, and I edited it :)

Comment: Tip for tiny edits: Add `<!--useful edit!-->` to the bottom of the text.